# exclamation mark before a NSString

Tags: objective-c, nsstring

Please do tell me what does an exclamation mark mean before a NSString

```
NSString *theString;
if (!theString);
```

cheers;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `!` symbol here (and in front of any expression whose type is a pointer) returns a true (1) result if the pointer is `NULL` and false (0) otherwise.  The `!theString` expression is then just a short way of saying `theString == NULL`.

Comment: so correct me if im wrong, the expression in the parenthesis evaluates to either 0 or 1, then `(!)` negates it?

Answer (score 3):

! is the boolean negation operation.  It inverts YES to NO and vice-versa.  NO is always equal to 0, while YES is any non-zero value, and as Jeremiah points out, a nil pointer is one that is set to `0x0`, or decimal 0.  Any pointer that isn't nil has a boolean value of TRUE.  So, `(!theString)` is equivalent to `(theString == nil)`.

Comment: "Any pointer that isn't nil has a boolean value of TRUE." I don't think that's true since this will print FALSE. NSLog(@"2 == TRUE? %@", 2 == TRUE ? @"TRUE" : @"FALSE")

Comment: You're right about that, and that's interesting.  I'm going to have to reconsider some assumptions and research this.  Thanks. :)

Comment: I did some experiments and here's what I determined.  Any non-zero value evaluates as true in a conditional statement.  However the constants TRUE, true, and YES are specifically set to 1.  So `2 != TRUE` but `if( 2 ){NSLog(@"It was true";}else{NSLog(@"It wasn't true";}` will print `It was true`.